# how to reflect the checkbox.oncheckchanged listener in one activity to another activity in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, checkbox, google-places-api

I have a requirement in which I have an activity which contains Checkboxes and the onChangedEvent of Checkbox should get reflected in other activity which is a map fragment. I am not understanding how to do it. Following is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
Spinner mSprPlaceType;  

String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;

Boolean isHospitalChecked;
Boolean isFireBrigadeChecked;
Boolean isPoliceStationChecked;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=null;


HashMap<String, String> mMarkerPlaceLink = new HashMap<String, String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("instantmessagingmap", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isHospitalChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hospital", false);
    isPoliceStationChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("police", false);
    isFireBrigadeChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("fire_station", false);

    // Array of place types
    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

    // Array of place type names
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

    // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
    // to populate the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

    // Getting reference to the Spinner 
    mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

    // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
    mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button btnFind;

    // Getting reference to Find Button
    btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Google Map
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlaceDetailsActivity.class);
                String reference = mMarkerPlaceLink.get(arg0.getId());
                intent.putExtra("reference", reference);

                // Starting the Place Details Activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        // Setting click event lister for the find button
        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewPlaces.class);
                startActivity(intent);


        /*      int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?fire");
                sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                sb.append("&radius=5000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("&key=AIzaSyChHq77IYR_BcjLejdOdUMkn43Ue0VWjeo");


                // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                placesTask.execute(sb.toString());*/


            }
        });

    }

    if(isHospitalChecked)
    {
        showMap("hospital");
    }
    if(isPoliceStationChecked)
    {
        showMap("police");
    }
    if(isFireBrigadeChecked)
    {
        showMap("fire_station");
    }

}

private void showMap(String place)
{

    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?hospital|police|fire_station");
    //sb.append(place);
    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=5000");
    //sb.append("&types=" + type);
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyChHq77IYR_BcjLejdOdUMkn43Ue0VWjeo");

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google
    // place json data
    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class
    // PlaceTask
    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());      
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();                

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}         


/** A class, to download Google Places */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }

}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

        // Clears all the existing markers 
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker. 
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);             

            // Linking Marker id and place reference
            mMarkerPlaceLink.put(m.getId(), hmPlace.get("reference"));              


        }       

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
}
```

My checkbox activity

```
public class ListViewPlaces extends Activity
{

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
TextView tvHospital;
TextView tvPoliceStation;
TextView tvFireBrigade;
CheckBox chBoxHospital;
CheckBox chBoxPoliceStations;
CheckBox chBoxFireBrigade;

Boolean isHospitalChecked;
Boolean isFireBrigadeChecked;
Boolean isPoliceStationChecked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_places);
    initView();
    setView();

}

private void setView()
{

    chBoxFireBrigade.setChecked(isFireBrigadeChecked);
    chBoxHospital.setChecked(isHospitalChecked);
    chBoxPoliceStations.setChecked(isPoliceStationChecked);
}

private void initView()
{

    tvHospital = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_tv_hospital);
    tvPoliceStation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_tv_police_staions);
    tvFireBrigade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_tv_fire_brigade);

    chBoxFireBrigade = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_ch_box_fire_brigade);
    chBoxHospital = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_ch_box_hospital);
    chBoxPoliceStations = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.list_view_places_ch_box_police_staions);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("instantMessaging", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isHospitalChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hospital", false);
    isPoliceStationChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("police_station", false);
    isFireBrigadeChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("fire", false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view_places, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    isHospitalChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hospital", false);
    isPoliceStationChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("police", false);
    isFireBrigadeChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("fire_station", false);


    if (chBoxFireBrigade.isChecked())
    {
        editor.putBoolean("fire_station", true);
    } else
    {
        editor.putBoolean("fire_station", false);
    }
    if (chBoxHospital.isChecked())
    {
        editor.putBoolean("hospital", true);
    } else
    {
        editor.putBoolean("hospital", false);
    }
    if (chBoxPoliceStations.isChecked())
    {
        editor.putBoolean("police", true);
    } else
    {
        editor.putBoolean("police", false);
    }
    editor.commit();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same `SharedPreferences` name in both, in order to write and read to the same table.

Change this line in `ListViewPlaces`:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("instantMessaging", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("instantmessagingmap", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Tried with this but still it isn't working. the places are not displayed. Onl,y the map is coming.

Comment: Did you check whether the flags are right? Maybe you have a display problen sonwwhere else.

Comment: Yes checked out the flags too, but not able to get the solution of the problem.